# What does `series_slot_num` parameter mean in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: configuration, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently scanning through the parameter settings of Apache IoTDB, and I noticed that there is a parameter `series_slot_num` for load balancing configuration. I want to know what does this parameter mean and what effect does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, there is no need to adjust this parameter in Apache IoTDB. This parameter means the number of buckets for the device ID.